# R counting variable sized lists occurrences

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of sorted sub lists of variable length. Each sub list is of variable size. I want to do two things. The first is sum the number of occurrences for each sub list. For example.

```
[[11533]]
[1] "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

[[11534]]
[1] "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

[[11535]]
[1] "Food"    "Grocery"    "dinner"
```

To

```
Count                 Item
2            "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

1           "Food"    "Grocery" "dinner"
```

And the second part is break each sub list into a vector and then sum each item. For example

```
[[11533]]
[1] "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

[[11534]]
[1] "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

[[11535]]
[1] "Food"     "Dinner"     "Grocery"
```

To

```
"Mexican"
"Restaurants"
"Mexican"
"Restaurants" 
"Food"    
"Dinner"    
"Grocery"
```

To

```
"Mexican" 2
"Restaurants" 2
"Food" 1    
"Dinner" 1    
"Grocery" 1
```

In python, I would use a for loop that looped through my primary list build a dictionary that be incremented by one every time I come across an item already in the dictionary. I'm a baby when it comes to R, however. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
tabled_data <- table(parsed_data)
```

tells me I need to have data that is of the same length

I also tried

```
for(i in length(parsed_data)){
  sum(parsed_data == parsed_data[i])
}
```

but I'm getting the error message "comparison of these types is not implemented"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `table` command:

```
testData <- list(c("Mexican","Restaurants"),c("Mexican","Restaurants"),c("Food","Grocery","dinner"))

# First question (join the vectors and then table them)
  table(sapply(testData,paste,collapse=""))

# Second problem (unlist the list and table it): 
  table(unlist(testData))
```

If the order within the vectors could change, you might want to sort them before pasting them.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. What does the collapse portion of sapply do to the list of characters?

Comment: The `collapse`option (for the `paste` command) specifies what you would like to have between the strings when you concatenate them, so maybe it would be even better to put there a whitespace instead of just `""`